# Why do I recover a deleted record with UCanAccess?

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I have been using UCanAccess to use Access databases my problem is when i want to delete a recor this returns automatically.
For example if i have:

```
Table Names

Id    Name
1    Jessy
2    Abraham

String deleteQuery = "DELETE From Names where Id =?";
PreparedStatement pstm = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
pstm.setInt(1, 1); // "id" is type numeric
pstm.executeUpdate();
pstm.close();
```

> it will works And then if i open the database the recor will be there!
>   that's my problem. (i hide the connection code but i have it)

Comment: Does `con.getConnection().getAutoCommit()` return `false` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using data type OLE to save images simple sentences doesn't works so the way to delete a row with OLE field is creating Database and Table objects from java. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use compact feature provided by Access.  On the Tools menu, point to Database Utilities, and then click Compact and Repair Database. This might help.

Comment: I have already tried it many times before without success. Anyway thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you do the commit after? If not and autocommit=false, just do it.